# Can I make the toolbar have two rows and still use menu items?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I am using the new appcompat Toolbar as an actionbar. I want to use menu items with `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` but I would also like to have buttons below the Toolbar which are part of the Toolbar layout. Not menu items but buttons and textviews I add myself. Hope that makes sense. Anyways how do I go about doing that? ideally the entire second row would have only my items whereas the top row would have the menu items.

Thanks.

EDIT: here is what I am talking about:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:hint="should extend full width" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Ends up looking like this:

[image]

Comment: try adding custom layout inside <Toolbar></Toolbar>.

Comment: When I've done that my layout ends up going from the left all the way to the first menu item, so I can't make it so it has two rows and that I can use the entire second row.

Comment: please post some code snippet here.

Comment: I have added my xml and a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually possible what you are saying to customize toolbar like that, as menu is controlled by system you cant handle that.

But you can do a workaround to achieve same effect like this,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:hint="Hello" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Button"/>
            </LinearLayout>
       <!--Other layout-->
```

Or wrap toolbar and linear layout in another linear layout to bind them togather.

It Should solve your purpose!

Answer (score -3):

You can always use reflection to do it:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("A really long title here to make sure we wrap text.");
    Field mTitleTextViewField = null;
    try {
        mTitleTextViewField = Toolbar.class.getDeclaredField("mTitleTextView");
        mTitleTextViewField.setAccessible(true);
        TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView)mTitleTextViewField.get(toolbar);
        mTitleTextView.setSingleLine(false);
        mTitleTextView.setMaxLines(2);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Because that's not the answer to the question. Not even close.